# How to upload image to digital Ocean Spaces using AWS SDK for Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, digital-ocean

> Since Digital Ocean Spaces API is compatible with AWS SDK, how to
>   upload images to Digital Ocean Spaces programmatically using AWS SDK
>   for Yii2?

Here my details

```
Good, we have the following data: 
1. endpoint: fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com
2. bucket name: dev-abc
3. api key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx and api secret: xxxxxxx
4. The url that you need to use to deliver assets is https://dev-abc
```

I have tried with this code whis is not working

```
$uploader = new FileUpload(FileUpload::S_S3, [
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'fra1',
    'endpoint' => 'https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx ',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxx'
    ],
    'bucket' => 'dev-abc'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here how i mange to go this**

Added the three libraries gulp,gulp-awspublish,gulp-rename

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var awspublish = require('gulp-awspublish');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var publisherDev = awspublish.create({
  region: 'fra1',
  params: {
    Bucket: 'dev-static-abc-ro'
  },
  accessKeyId: 'XCCCCCZX',
  secretAccessKey: 'EDKDJKJDKDJ',
  endpoint: 'fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
});
```

Now added the function
// dev server

```
gulp.task('dev', function() {
  // console.log("Hi! I'm Gulp default task root!");
  return gulp
    .src('./temp-dist/**')
    .pipe(
      rename(function(path) {
        path.dirname += '/assets';
        // path.basename += "-s3";
      })
    )
    .pipe(publisherDev.publish())
    .pipe(publisherDev.sync('assets/'))
    .pipe(awspublish.reporter());
});
```

Run the command

> gulp dev

Answer (score 4):

You can php code to upload image in digital ocean:

1. Configure a client:

   use Aws\S3\S3Client;

   ```
   $client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
       'version' => 'latest',
       'region'  => 'us-east-1',
       'endpoint' => 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
       'credentials' => [
           'key'    => getenv('SPACES_KEY'),
           'secret' => getenv('SPACES_SECRET'),
       ],
   ]);
   ```
2. Create a New Space

   ```
   $client->createBucket([
       'Bucket' => 'example-space-name',
   ]);
   ```
3. Upload Image

   ```
   $client->putObject([
       'Bucket' => 'example-space-name',
       'Key'    => 'file.ext',
       'Body'   => 'The contents of the file.',
       'ACL'    => 'private'
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Install composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and then run the following to setup the AWS PHP dependencies:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

The following code has a form for uploading images, the code processes the files and uploads them to DO Spaces. Replace your values with those in the code.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];   
            $temp_file_location = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
    
            $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
                'region'  => '-- your region --',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => "-- access key id --",
                    'secret' => "-- secret access key --",
                ]
            ]);     
    
            $result = $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => '-- bucket name --',
                'Key'    => $file_name,
                'SourceFile' => $temp_file_location         
            ]);
    
            var_dump($result);
        }
    ?>
    
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">         
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: People doing a downvote should have the decency to post the reason.