# Angular 2 deploy in server and add asset to go bucket via ci/cd and consume asset from bucket CDN

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, bucket

Here i am working wit CI/CD Using Gitlab CI.
When i added this command
`npm run build:dev --progress false --output-hashing=all --deploy-url https://dev-static.abc.ro/`
The --deploy-url is changing the path of all the assets that is fine

How can i add these asset folder or dist folder to go bucket  via ci/cd  using the credential of  go bucket.

Here the commands which i am using to deploy project on my server

```
`
rm package-lock.json
npm install
npm install @angular/cli
npm run build:dev --progress false --output-hashing=all --deploy-url https://dev-static.abc.ro/

printf "\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"
printf "# Remove current dist folder and Move files from temp-dist to dist  #\n"
printf "###############################################################################\n"

rm -rf dist/*
mv temp-dist/* dist/
`
```

Here the code outlook
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gulp` for this
Please the answer no 2 given in the following question

[How to upload image to digital Ocean Spaces using AWS SDK for Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937975/how-to-upload-image-to-digital-ocean-spaces-using-aws-sdk-for-yii2/61626057#61626057)